# Add 0 values to existing plot in R within specified interval

Tags: r, plot

I have an existing plot in R,

```
z <- seq(20, 50, by=1)
plot (z, (3 / (z+1))^5, type="b", xlab=expression(theta), ylab=expression(paste("P(",theta,")")))
```

[image]

The function I'm plotting is only defined for values greater than 20.  How would I reflect this in my plot for values from 0 to 19?  There should be a point at 0 on the y-axis for each discrete number 1:19 on the x-axis, and then from 20 onward, the plot is as I currently have it.

I tried using ablines(), but I can only get a line throughout the entire plot, not for a range, and I can't get it to be dots (preferred since the function is only defined for discrete values).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just generate the points you already have, then concatenate them with a bunch of zeros.

```
z <- seq(20, 50, by=1)
y <- (3 / (z+1))^5

z <- c(1:20,20:50)
y <- c(rep(0, 20), y)
plot (z, y, xlab=expression(theta), type="b",
    ylab=expression(paste("P(",theta,")")))
```

[image: Extended Plot]